# Alert Box Asking User to Grant Location Privileges is not showing

Tags: ios, swift

I am just getting started with SWIFT programming on iOS. However I have good experience in other languages such as JAVA, C# and PHP. That said, I am running into a little bit of a problem. I am creating a simple application that will show a user information based on their geographical location. I am following the tutorial listed [here](https://www.appcoda.com/geo-targeting-ios/).

However, since a lot of things have changed between Swift 2.x and 3.x I have had to modify his code. Not too hard and so far I have gotten it to compile. However, I am never asked by the application to allow me to use the device's location.

I have followed the directions Apple listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) about putting "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" in the Info.plist. However I am never prompted. The relevant piece of code that should be showing this alert is listed below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // 1. status is not determined
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
        // 2. authorization were denied
    else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied {
        let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Location services were previously denied. Please enable location services for this app in Settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .destructive) { (action) in
            print("Dismiss button tapped!")
        }

        controller.addAction(alertAction)

    }
        // 3. we do have authorization
    else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yuck. Do you know about `switch`?

Comment: @matt This is not production code. I was just trying to get a mapView to work. I am new to iOS programming so please forgive the the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine you just need to present your alert:

```
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And also take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861941/check-if-location-services-are-enabled/34862296#34862296) how you can use `switch` for this types of code.