# Prompt user when turning off location service from Settings when app is not running

Tags: ios, background, core-location, location-services

I want my app users to keep Location Service Turned ON all the time. This is the requirement of the application which will keep checking user is on the job location even after app is not running or killed. I know this can be achieved by enabling Background Mode : Location Updates. I have referred the Location updates which help me getting updates even after app is killed.

Now, I want to notify users when they turn off Location service if app is not running.
How can i determine the status of Location Service after app is killed/Not running ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if location services are enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861941/check-if-location-services-are-enabled)

Comment: thanks jason for responding. I am looking for a solution when app is not running.